# Running a t-test in Excel on time data that crosses midnight

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to run a t-test on the bedtimes of teenagers but the data values cross midnight.

I found this formula for calculating the mean bedtime:
`=AVERAGE((IF(B2:B118<>"",IF(B2:B118<--"12:00:00",B2:B118+1,B2:B118))))`

but when I run the t-test the mean times are clearly incorrect.

I don't think the code for running the t-test in excel can handle different time values am/pm.

I thought about converting to 24 hour time but I don't think that would work either.

It would average 11pm and midnight as 11:30 am.

Comment: It may be best to post a sample of your data, mainly what the the time cells look like. At this point I believe your time comparison in the formula is the error, you are comparing to 12 noon and not 12 midnight. Having said that, I don't think you can compare to 12 midnight. I think exploring 24 hour format with your formula, or transforming your data where before midnight is negative and after midnight is positive could do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

*I would like to suggest two possible method finds `Mean/Average` time, `between before midnight and after midnight`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula for `Method 1` (Helper Time Method) in Cell `G38`.

`=IF(F38<0.5,F38+1,F38)`

- Fill formula down.
- An array (CSE) formula in Cell `G49`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

  `{=AVERAGE(TIME(HOUR(G38:G47),MINUTE(G38:G47),SECOND(G38:G47)))}`
- Array (CSE) formula for `Method 2` in Cell `G51` (avoids Helper Time Method).

`{=AVERAGE((F38:F47)+(F38:F47<0.5))}`

**N.B.**

- Adds a day to any time earlier than noon before get average.
- You may also apply `NUMBER` cell Format on `G38:G47`.
- Basically `DATE` & `TIME` are `Numeric data` therefore while applying suggested formula Excel successfully evaluates `TIME` to get results.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This is a great answer but not very intuitive. The screenshot shows rows with the same values in `F` and `G` that actually contain different data. I find it helpful to think about in terms of pure numbers; with 86400 seconds in a day, convert all the times to seconds and add 86400 to any that are after midnight (using whatever test for 'after midnight' fits the shape of the data). Then average, and convert seconds back to time. In other words, you're averaging times where 10PM is 22:00, 11PM is 23:00, 12AM is 24:00 and 1AM is 25:00, etc.

Comment: @AlexM,, thanks for valuable observation,, actually by mistake I've missed to change the Cell Format of Col G,, it should Numeric , but since DATE & TIME are originally NUMBERS so that the suggested Formula evaluates all in NUMBER to execute further.